# Re-position image or DIV with .position() and have elements collapse to fill space

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Using [.position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) for jQuery UI, I'm able to successfully move an image to the end of a list of images... however I'm not sure how to get the other images to "move up" to fill the space.

I know the moved image is given relative positioning, which I believe is what is causing the other images to "stay" in their places.  The problem is I'm not sure how to move the other ones up. (without moving EVERY image, every-time another image around it is moved, which I can't see how it would be possible when I could have any unknown number of images loading)

Ideally I'd like to move the entire DIV on the DOM, with animation, but I can't figure out how to do that, so I've had to fall back to using .position()

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pzeudy4f/3/)

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#elemA').position({
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left bottom',
    of: $('#elemC'),
    collision: 'none',
    using: function(pos) {
      $(this).animate(pos, "fast")
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>

  <button id="btn">click</button>


  <div id="elemA">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/l1wpxNXG9.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="elemB">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/l1xYdbrhS.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="elemC">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/l1yt0skhN.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Would something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/pzeudy4f/6/) work for you?**

I didn't change any of your HTML, and all I did in the CSS is make the images `position:absolute`, so here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('name', i).css({
      top: 40 + ($(this).attr('name') * 155) + 'px'
    })
  }); // Set the initial image positions
  $('#btn').click(moveImages); // Add click handler to button
});

function moveImages() {
  $('img').each(function() { // Loop over all your images
    var imgNum = $(this).attr('name'); // Grab the numerical name
    $(this).attr('name', imgNum - 1); // Whatever that number is, subtract 1
    $('img[name=-1]').attr('name', $('img').length - 1); // Change the -1 to be the highest number
    $(this).animate({
      top: 40 + ($(this).attr('name') * 155) + 'px'
    }); // Multiply the new number by 155, and animate to that position
  });
}
```

Hopefully my comments make sense, but here's the not-so-basic rundown:

1. Now that your images are positioned absolutely, they are all in the top left corner. In order to have them neatly displayed in a vertical column, we need to give them a `top` amount. But how much? Well, each image is about 150 pixels high, and if we add a 5-pixel buffer to the bottom, that's 155. The first image is easy; it needs to be at `top:0` (or 155 * 0). The second image should be at `top:155px` or (155 * 1). The third should be at `top:310px` (or 155 * 2). See the pattern? *(Note: I added 40 pixels to each of these numbers later, to give room for the button at the top.)*
2. So I used `.each()` to loop over all the images, and with a jQuery `.attr()` method, I gave each image `name="x"`, where x is starting at 0 and going up by one per image. Then with `.css()` I gave each image `top:x * 155`, again, where x is that image's `name`.
3. So now I want the first image (`name="0"`) to go to where the third image is, and the second image to go where the first image is, and the third image to go where the second image is. All I have to do is set the first image's name to 2 (so it's `top` becomes 155 * 2), the second image's name to 0, and the third image's name to 1. Really all I'm doing is decreasing every image's name (except the first one) by 1. So that's what I do in the `moveImages` function.
4. For the first image, I actually decrease its name by 1 as well, so it becomes -1. Then I select the image with a `name` of -1, and set its name to **the total number of images minus 1**, which is 2. That means, this code will work no matter how many images you have.

I hope this helps! If it doesn't exactly solve your problem, I'd be glad to edit my code.